# FE1.1s Based USB hub - USB device descriptor failed

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I designed a PCB which has a FE1.1s USB Hub controller. This project must work as a micro-USB HUB. The problem is that when I connect my device to computer, my board's LEDs turn on for a moment and everything goes off again. "device not recognized" error appears and says "A request for the USB device descriptor failed."

Before this I thought that because my usage is a simple BUS- Powered HUB I don't need to program the chip (or config device descriptor parameters) but now I think I should.

My question is: How to program it? What should Product ID and vendor ID be? Is there any kind of table for these? What kind of tools do I need for this process? Do I need to add an EEPROM to my design or is the programming just for the first time?

The attached file is my reference circuit and another schematic with some changes to make it bus powered and also the datasheet and errors.

It would be a great help if anyone guide me to solve this problem.

[FE1.1S datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2991/FE1.1s+Data+Sheet+(Rev.+1.0).pdf)

[image: my schematic]
*Figure 1. My schematic*

[image: reference circuit]
*Figure 2. Reference circuit*

[image: error]
*Figure 3. Error*

Comment: what happens if you plug a USB device into the hub?

Comment: the pin 19 is tied high, which indicates a self-powered device, but there is no power supply

Comment: pin 19 is an indicator and doesn't change any thing

Comment: and it is also tied down to ground.

Comment: @HamidrezaHassanvand Usually these kind of issues occurs when something is not ok on the USB traces. Would you please create a snapshot from the USB traces (in the layout design and the real hardware as well)? How are they connected? Sometimes series resistors helps. If you search in google 'usb breakout board' then you can get this small usb board and using air wires to connect it into your dev board. And you can attach series resistors of 27ohm to the path of D+ and D-.

Answer (score 1):

Input D+ & D- are swapped. This error exists on many of these schematics

Comment: If you're talking about the DMU and DPU pins, yes, the reference circuit (figure 2) differs from 'My schematic' (figure 1). But the datasheet says that DMU is 'The D- pin of the Upstream Facing Port' and DPU is 'The D+ pin of the Upstream Facing Port'. So the reference schematic seems to be in the wrong, not the OP.