RTL2832U EEPROM FW, Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)
How to flash config into just produced SDR based on the RTL2832U?
And what exactly to flash?
With empty flash - windows gave an error Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)
The schematic USB part and power part was made according to the datasheet.



I won't write an answer because I'm not completely sure. But I don't THINK that you should have to flash anything onto the EEPROM. If not, the device should default to some Realtek settings. It should still enumerate correctly. So my guess is that you've gotten some hardware wrong.

Hi, thank you for the comment, i also was thinking about that - but i double checked everything and found this post (without the solution) - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595971/developed-usb-device-not-recognized-on-windows-linux-device-descriptor-error

The RTL2832U brief says that the flash-based configuration is optional, for customization. Usually this kind of ICs do have multiple HW startup configurations, including some default configuration. You need to find the proper strapping option, and everything should work.
If you need some custom configuration, aka "what to write to flash", they likely have some special tool to configure the custom flash file with all necessary bit setting, but it might be challenging to get it from RealTek unless you plan to buy 100,000 chips from them per month :-(
It is also wise to check POR (power-on reset) and if the clock is supplied, and with correct frequency.

Hi, in most of the cases it is like that - but not with this particular IC. Datasheet says that config is in the EEPROM. I tried to remove the FLASH completely - result is the same.
